# onGpsLocationChanged not being called

Tags: android, gps

I'm making an app whitch is drawing itinerary on google map done by the phone.

I use coordinates(from android.location.Location) and available satellites amount(from android.location.GpsSatellite) for this.
Sometimes problems with getting location occur, mostly on speed while moving by car. onLocationChanges stops being called for some period of time, and at precisely at this time satellite number drops to zero.

Here is the log example:
Good:

```
31.05 15:21:47 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:22, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:47 6/19
31.05 15:21:47 6/19
31.05 15:21:46 6/19
31.05 15:21:46 6/19
31.05 15:21:45 6/19
31.05 15:21:45 6/19
31.05 15:21:44 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:19, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:43 5/19
31.05 15:21:43 5/19
31.05 15:21:42 5/19
31.05 15:21:42 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:17, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:42 5/19
31.05 15:21:41 5/19
31.05 15:21:41 5/19
31.05 15:21:40 5/19
31.05 15:21:40 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:15, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:40 5/19
31.05 15:21:39 5/18
31.05 15:21:39 5/18
31.05 15:21:39 6/19
31.05 15:21:38 6/19
31.05 15:21:38 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:13, Coordinates: lat = xxx, = xxx
31.05 15:21:38 6/19
31.05 15:21:38 6/19
31.05 15:21:36 6/19
31.05 15:21:36 6/19
31.05 15:21:35 6/19
31.05 15:21:35 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:10, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:35 6/19
31.05 15:21:34 6/18
31.05 15:21:34 6/18
31.05 15:21:34 7/19
31.05 15:21:34 7/19
31.05 15:21:33 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:08, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:32 7/19
31.05 15:21:32 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:07, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:32 7/19
31.05 15:21:31 7/18
31.05 15:21:31 7/18
31.05 15:21:30 7/18
31.05 15:21:30 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:05, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:30 7/18
31.05 15:21:30 7/19
31.05 15:21:29 7/19
31.05 15:21:29 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:04, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:28 6/18
31.05 15:21:28 6/18
31.05 15:21:27 8/19
31.05 15:21:27 8/19
31.05 15:21:26 8/19
31.05 15:21:26 time = 2016-05-31 15:20:01, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:26 8/19
31.05 15:21:25 8/19
31.05 15:21:25 8/19
31.05 15:21:24 8/19
31.05 15:21:24 8/19
31.05 15:21:23 8/19
31.05 15:21:23 time = 2016-05-31 15:19:58, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:21:23 8/19
31.05 15:21:22 8/18
31.05 15:21:22 8/18
31.05 15:21:22 9/19
31.05 15:21:22 9/19
31.05 15:21:20 9/19
31.05 15:21:20 time = 2016-05-31 15:19:55, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
```

Bad:

```
31.05 15:33:52 12/19
31.05 15:33:51 12/19
31.05 15:33:50 12/19
31.05 15:33:50 12/19
31.05 15:33:50 12/19
31.05 15:33:49 time = 2016-05-31 15:32:24, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:33:49 11/19
31.05 15:33:48 time = 2016-05-31 15:32:23, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:33:47 7/19
31.05 15:33:46 7/19
31.05 15:33:45 4/18
31.05 15:33:45 4/18
31.05 15:33:43 4/18
31.05 15:33:43 1/18
31.05 15:33:42 1/18
31.05 15:33:40 1/18
31.05 15:33:39 1/18
31.05 15:33:38 1/18
31.05 15:33:37 1/18
31.05 15:33:36 1/18
31.05 15:33:35 1/18
31.05 15:33:34 1/18
31.05 15:33:34 1/17
31.05 15:33:32 0/18
31.05 15:33:31 0/18
31.05 15:33:30 0/18
31.05 15:33:29 0/18
31.05 15:33:28 0/18
31.05 15:33:27 0/18
31.05 15:33:26 0/18
31.05 15:33:25 0/18
31.05 15:33:24 0/18
31.05 15:33:23 0/18
31.05 15:33:22 0/18
31.05 15:33:21 0/17
31.05 15:33:20 0/18
31.05 15:33:20 0/18
31.05 15:33:18 0/18
31.05 15:33:17 0/18
31.05 15:33:16 0/18
31.05 15:33:15 0/18
31.05 15:33:14 0/18
31.05 15:33:13 0/18
31.05 15:33:12 0/18
31.05 15:33:11 0/18
31.05 15:33:10 0/18
31.05 15:33:09 0/18
31.05 15:33:08 0/18
31.05 15:33:07 0/18
31.05 15:33:06 0/18
31.05 15:33:05 0/18
31.05 15:33:04 0/18
31.05 15:33:03 0/18
31.05 15:33:02 0/18
31.05 15:33:01 0/18
31.05 15:33:00 0/18
31.05 15:32:59 0/17
31.05 15:32:58 0/17
31.05 15:32:57 1/18
31.05 15:32:56 1/18
31.05 15:32:55 1/18
31.05 15:32:54 1/18
31.05 15:32:54 1/18
31.05 15:32:52 1/18
31.05 15:32:51 1/18
31.05 15:32:50 1/18
31.05 15:32:49 1/18
31.05 15:32:49 1/18
31.05 15:32:47 1/18
31.05 15:32:46 1/18
31.05 15:32:45 1/18
31.05 15:32:44 1/18
31.05 15:32:43 1/17
31.05 15:32:42 1/18
31.05 15:32:41 1/18
31.05 15:32:40 1/17
31.05 15:32:39 2/18
31.05 15:32:38 2/17
31.05 15:32:37 3/18
31.05 15:32:36 3/18
31.05 15:32:35 3/18
31.05 15:32:34 3/18
31.05 15:32:33 2/18
31.05 15:32:32 2/18
31.05 15:32:31 2/18
31.05 15:32:31 2/18
31.05 15:32:29 2/18
31.05 15:32:28 2/18
31.05 15:32:27 2/18
31.05 15:32:26 2/18
31.05 15:32:25 2/17
31.05 15:32:24 2/18
31.05 15:32:24 2/18
31.05 15:32:22 2/18
31.05 15:32:21 2/18
31.05 15:32:20 2/18
31.05 15:32:19 2/18
31.05 15:32:18 2/18
31.05 15:32:17 2/17
31.05 15:32:16 3/18
31.05 15:32:15 3/18
31.05 15:32:15 3/18
31.05 15:32:13 3/18
31.05 15:32:12 3/18
31.05 15:32:11 3/18
31.05 15:32:10 3/18
31.05 15:32:09 3/18
31.05 15:32:08 3/18
31.05 15:32:08 3/18
31.05 15:32:06 3/18
31.05 15:32:05 3/18
31.05 15:32:04 3/18
31.05 15:32:03 3/18
31.05 15:32:02 3/18
31.05 15:32:01 3/18
31.05 15:32:00 3/18
31.05 15:31:59 3/18
31.05 15:31:58 3/18
31.05 15:31:57 2/18
31.05 15:31:57 2/18
31.05 15:31:56 2/18
31.05 15:31:54 2/18
31.05 15:31:53 2/18
31.05 15:31:52 2/18
31.05 15:31:51 2/18
31.05 15:31:50 2/18
31.05 15:31:49 1/18
31.05 15:31:48 1/18
31.05 15:31:47 1/18
31.05 15:31:46 1/18
31.05 15:31:45 1/18
31.05 15:31:44 1/18
31.05 15:31:43 1/18
31.05 15:31:42 1/18
31.05 15:31:41 1/18
31.05 15:31:40 1/18
31.05 15:31:40 1/18
31.05 15:31:38 1/18
31.05 15:31:37 1/18
31.05 15:31:36 1/18
31.05 15:31:35 1/18
31.05 15:31:34 1/18
31.05 15:31:33 1/18
31.05 15:31:33 1/18
31.05 15:31:31 1/18
31.05 15:31:31 1/18
31.05 15:31:29 1/18
31.05 15:31:28 1/18
31.05 15:31:27 1/18
31.05 15:31:26 1/18
31.05 15:31:25 1/18
31.05 15:31:24 1/18
31.05 15:31:23 1/18
31.05 15:31:22 1/18
31.05 15:31:21 1/18
31.05 15:31:20 1/18
31.05 15:31:19 1/18
31.05 15:31:18 1/18
31.05 15:31:17 1/18
31.05 15:31:16 1/18
31.05 15:31:15 1/18
31.05 15:31:14 1/18
31.05 15:31:13 1/18
31.05 15:31:12 1/18
31.05 15:31:11 1/18
31.05 15:31:10 1/18
31.05 15:31:09 1/18
31.05 15:31:08 1/18
31.05 15:31:07 0/18
31.05 15:31:06 0/18
31.05 15:31:05 0/18
31.05 15:31:05 0/18
31.05 15:31:03 0/18
31.05 15:31:02 0/18
31.05 15:31:01 0/18
31.05 15:31:00 0/18
31.05 15:30:59 0/18
31.05 15:30:58 0/18
31.05 15:30:57 0/18
31.05 15:30:56 0/18
31.05 15:30:55 0/18
31.05 15:30:54 0/18
31.05 15:30:53 0/18
31.05 15:30:52 0/18
31.05 15:30:51 0/18
31.05 15:30:50 0/18
31.05 15:30:49 0/18
31.05 15:30:48 0/18
31.05 15:30:47 0/18
31.05 15:30:46 0/18
31.05 15:30:45 0/18
31.05 15:30:44 0/18
31.05 15:30:43 0/18
31.05 15:30:42 0/18
31.05 15:30:41 0/18
31.05 15:30:40 0/18
31.05 15:30:39 0/18
31.05 15:30:38 0/18
31.05 15:30:37 0/18
31.05 15:30:36 0/18
31.05 15:30:36 0/18
31.05 15:30:34 0/18
31.05 15:30:33 0/18
31.05 15:30:32 0/17
31.05 15:30:31 1/18
31.05 15:30:30 1/18
31.05 15:30:29 1/18
31.05 15:30:28 1/18
31.05 15:30:27 1/18
31.05 15:30:26 1/18
31.05 15:30:25 1/18
31.05 15:30:24 1/18
31.05 15:30:23 1/18
31.05 15:30:22 1/18
31.05 15:30:21 1/18
31.05 15:30:20 1/18
31.05 15:30:19 1/18
31.05 15:30:18 1/18
31.05 15:30:17 1/18
31.05 15:30:16 1/18
31.05 15:30:15 1/18
31.05 15:30:14 1/18
31.05 15:30:13 1/18
31.05 15:30:12 1/18
31.05 15:30:11 1/18
31.05 15:30:10 1/18
31.05 15:30:09 1/18
31.05 15:30:08 0/18
31.05 15:30:07 0/18
31.05 15:30:06 0/18
31.05 15:30:05 0/18
31.05 15:30:04 0/18
31.05 15:30:04 0/18
31.05 15:30:03 0/18
31.05 15:30:01 0/18
31.05 15:30:00 0/18
31.05 15:29:59 0/18
31.05 15:29:58 0/18
31.05 15:29:57 0/18
31.05 15:29:56 0/18
31.05 15:29:55 0/18
31.05 15:29:54 0/18
31.05 15:29:53 0/18
31.05 15:29:52 0/18
31.05 15:29:51 0/18
31.05 15:29:50 0/18
31.05 15:29:49 0/18
31.05 15:29:48 0/18
31.05 15:29:47 0/18
31.05 15:29:46 0/18
31.05 15:29:45 0/18
31.05 15:29:44 0/18
31.05 15:29:43 0/18
31.05 15:29:42 0/18
31.05 15:29:41 0/18
31.05 15:29:40 0/18
31.05 15:29:39 0/18
31.05 15:29:38 0/18
31.05 15:29:37 0/18
31.05 15:29:36 0/18
31.05 15:29:35 0/18
31.05 15:29:34 0/18
31.05 15:29:33 0/18
31.05 15:29:32 0/18
31.05 15:29:32 0/18
31.05 15:29:30 0/18
31.05 15:29:29 0/18
31.05 15:29:28 0/18
31.05 15:29:27 0/18
31.05 15:29:26 0/18
31.05 15:29:25 0/18
31.05 15:29:24 0/18
31.05 15:29:23 0/17
31.05 15:29:22 0/18
31.05 15:29:21 0/18
31.05 15:29:20 0/18
31.05 15:29:19 0/18
31.05 15:29:18 0/18
31.05 15:29:17 0/18
31.05 15:29:16 0/18
31.05 15:29:15 0/18
31.05 15:29:14 0/18
31.05 15:29:13 0/18
31.05 15:29:12 0/18
31.05 15:29:11 0/18
31.05 15:29:10 0/18
31.05 15:29:09 0/18
31.05 15:29:08 0/18
31.05 15:29:07 0/18
31.05 15:29:06 0/18
31.05 15:29:06 0/18
31.05 15:29:04 0/18
31.05 15:29:03 0/18
31.05 15:29:02 0/18
31.05 15:29:01 0/18
31.05 15:29:00 0/18
31.05 15:28:59 0/18
31.05 15:28:58 0/18
31.05 15:28:57 0/18
31.05 15:28:56 0/18
31.05 15:28:55 0/18
31.05 15:28:54 0/18
31.05 15:28:53 0/18
31.05 15:28:52 0/18
31.05 15:28:52 0/18
31.05 15:28:50 0/18
31.05 15:28:49 0/18
31.05 15:28:48 0/18
31.05 15:28:47 0/18
31.05 15:28:46 0/18
31.05 15:28:45 0/18
31.05 15:28:44 0/18
31.05 15:28:43 0/18
31.05 15:28:43 0/18
31.05 15:28:41 0/18
31.05 15:28:40 0/18
31.05 15:28:39 0/18
31.05 15:28:38 0/18
31.05 15:28:37 0/18
31.05 15:28:36 0/18
31.05 15:28:35 0/18
31.05 15:28:34 0/18
31.05 15:28:33 0/18
31.05 15:28:32 0/18
31.05 15:28:31 0/18
31.05 15:28:30 0/18
31.05 15:28:29 0/18
31.05 15:28:28 0/18
31.05 15:28:27 0/18
31.05 15:28:26 0/18
31.05 15:28:25 0/18
31.05 15:28:24 0/18
31.05 15:28:23 0/18
31.05 15:28:22 0/17
31.05 15:28:22 0/17
31.05 15:28:20 1/18
31.05 15:28:19 1/18
31.05 15:28:18 1/18
31.05 15:28:17 1/18
31.05 15:28:16 1/18
31.05 15:28:15 1/18
31.05 15:28:14 1/18
31.05 15:28:13 1/18
31.05 15:28:12 1/18
31.05 15:28:11 1/18
31.05 15:28:10 1/18
31.05 15:28:09 1/18
31.05 15:28:08 1/18
31.05 15:28:07 1/18
31.05 15:28:06 1/18
31.05 15:28:05 1/18
31.05 15:28:04 1/18
31.05 15:28:03 1/18
31.05 15:28:03 1/18
31.05 15:28:01 1/18
31.05 15:28:00 1/18
31.05 15:27:59 1/18
31.05 15:27:58 1/18
31.05 15:27:57 1/18
31.05 15:27:56 1/18
31.05 15:27:55 1/18
31.05 15:27:54 1/18
31.05 15:27:53 1/18
31.05 15:27:52 1/18
31.05 15:27:51 1/18
31.05 15:27:50 1/18
31.05 15:27:49 1/18
31.05 15:27:48 1/18
31.05 15:27:47 1/17
31.05 15:27:46 2/18
31.05 15:27:45 2/18
31.05 15:27:44 2/18
31.05 15:27:43 2/17
31.05 15:27:42 2/17
31.05 15:27:41 3/17
31.05 15:27:40 4/18
31.05 15:27:39 4/18
31.05 15:27:38 4/18
31.05 15:27:37 4/18
31.05 15:27:36 4/18
31.05 15:27:35 4/18
31.05 15:27:34 4/18
31.05 15:27:33 4/18
31.05 15:27:32 4/18
31.05 15:27:31 4/18
31.05 15:27:30 4/18
31.05 15:27:29 4/18
31.05 15:27:28 4/18
31.05 15:27:27 4/18
31.05 15:27:26 4/18
31.05 15:27:25 4/18
31.05 15:27:24 4/18
31.05 15:27:23 4/18
31.05 15:27:22 4/18
31.05 15:27:21 4/18
31.05 15:27:20 4/18
31.05 15:27:19 4/18
31.05 15:27:18 4/18
31.05 15:27:17 4/18
31.05 15:27:16 4/18
31.05 15:27:16 4/18
31.05 15:27:14 4/18
31.05 15:27:13 4/18
31.05 15:27:12 4/18
31.05 15:27:11 4/18
31.05 15:27:10 4/18
31.05 15:27:09 4/18
31.05 15:27:08 4/18
31.05 15:27:07 4/18
31.05 15:27:06 4/18
31.05 15:27:05 4/18
31.05 15:27:04 4/18
31.05 15:27:03 4/18
31.05 15:27:02 4/18
31.05 15:27:01 4/18
31.05 15:27:00 4/18
31.05 15:26:59 3/18
31.05 15:26:58 2/18
31.05 15:26:57 0/17
31.05 15:26:56 1/17
31.05 15:26:55 1/17
31.05 15:26:54 2/18
31.05 15:26:54 2/18
31.05 15:26:52 2/18
31.05 15:26:51 2/18
31.05 15:26:50 2/18
31.05 15:26:49 2/18
31.05 15:26:48 2/18
31.05 15:26:47 2/18
31.05 15:26:46 2/18
31.05 15:26:45 2/17
31.05 15:26:45 2/17
31.05 15:26:43 2/17
31.05 15:26:42 2/18
31.05 15:26:41 2/18
31.05 15:26:41 2/18
31.05 15:26:39 2/18
31.05 15:26:38 2/18
31.05 15:26:37 2/18
31.05 15:26:36 2/18
31.05 15:26:35 2/18
31.05 15:26:34 1/18
31.05 15:26:33 1/18
31.05 15:26:32 1/18
31.05 15:26:31 1/18
31.05 15:26:30 1/18
31.05 15:26:29 1/18
31.05 15:26:29 1/18
31.05 15:26:27 1/18
31.05 15:26:26 1/18
31.05 15:26:25 1/18
31.05 15:26:24 1/18
31.05 15:26:23 0/18
31.05 15:26:23 0/17
31.05 15:26:21 1/18
31.05 15:26:20 1/18
31.05 15:26:19 1/18
31.05 15:26:18 1/18
31.05 15:26:17 1/18
31.05 15:26:16 1/18
31.05 15:26:15 1/18
31.05 15:26:14 1/18
31.05 15:26:13 1/18
31.05 15:26:12 1/18
31.05 15:26:11 1/18
31.05 15:26:11 1/18
31.05 15:26:09 1/18
31.05 15:26:08 1/18
31.05 15:26:07 1/18
31.05 15:26:06 1/18
31.05 15:26:05 1/18
31.05 15:26:04 1/18
31.05 15:26:03 1/18
31.05 15:26:02 1/18
31.05 15:26:01 0/18
31.05 15:26:00 0/18
31.05 15:25:59 0/18
31.05 15:25:58 0/18
31.05 15:25:57 0/18
31.05 15:25:56 0/18
31.05 15:25:55 0/18
31.05 15:25:54 0/18
31.05 15:25:53 0/18
31.05 15:25:52 0/18
31.05 15:25:51 0/18
31.05 15:25:50 0/18
31.05 15:25:49 0/18
31.05 15:25:48 0/18
31.05 15:25:47 0/18
31.05 15:25:46 0/18
31.05 15:25:45 0/17
31.05 15:25:44 0/18
31.05 15:25:43 0/18
31.05 15:25:42 0/18
31.05 15:25:41 0/18
31.05 15:25:40 0/18
31.05 15:25:39 0/18
31.05 15:25:38 0/18
31.05 15:25:37 0/18
31.05 15:25:36 0/18
31.05 15:25:35 0/18
31.05 15:25:34 0/18
31.05 15:25:33 0/18
31.05 15:25:32 0/18
31.05 15:25:31 0/18
31.05 15:25:30 0/18
31.05 15:25:29 0/18
31.05 15:25:28 0/18
31.05 15:25:27 0/18
31.05 15:25:26 0/18
31.05 15:25:25 0/18
31.05 15:25:25 0/18
31.05 15:25:23 0/18
31.05 15:25:22 0/18
31.05 15:25:21 0/18
31.05 15:25:20 0/18
31.05 15:25:19 0/18
31.05 15:25:18 0/18
31.05 15:25:17 0/18
31.05 15:25:16 0/18
31.05 15:25:16 0/18
31.05 15:25:14 0/18
31.05 15:25:13 0/18
31.05 15:25:12 0/18
31.05 15:25:11 0/18
31.05 15:25:10 0/17
31.05 15:25:09 0/17
31.05 15:25:08 1/18
31.05 15:25:07 1/18
31.05 15:25:06 1/18
31.05 15:25:05 1/18
31.05 15:25:04 1/18
31.05 15:25:03 1/18
31.05 15:25:02 1/18
31.05 15:25:01 1/18
31.05 15:25:00 1/17
31.05 15:24:59 1/17
31.05 15:24:58 1/17
31.05 15:24:57 2/18
31.05 15:24:56 2/18
31.05 15:24:55 2/18
31.05 15:24:54 2/18
31.05 15:24:53 2/18
31.05 15:24:52 2/18
31.05 15:24:51 2/18
31.05 15:24:50 2/18
31.05 15:24:49 2/18
31.05 15:24:48 2/17
31.05 15:24:47 2/18
31.05 15:24:46 2/18
31.05 15:24:45 2/18
31.05 15:24:44 2/18
31.05 15:24:43 2/18
31.05 15:24:42 2/18
31.05 15:24:41 2/18
31.05 15:24:40 2/18
31.05 15:24:39 2/17
31.05 15:24:38 3/17
31.05 15:24:37 4/18
31.05 15:24:36 4/18
31.05 15:24:35 3/18
31.05 15:24:34 3/18
31.05 15:24:33 3/18
31.05 15:24:32 3/18
31.05 15:24:31 3/18
31.05 15:24:30 3/18
31.05 15:24:29 3/18
31.05 15:24:28 3/18
31.05 15:24:27 3/18
31.05 15:24:26 3/18
31.05 15:24:25 3/18
31.05 15:24:24 3/18
31.05 15:24:23 3/18
31.05 15:24:23 3/18
31.05 15:24:21 3/18
31.05 15:24:20 3/18
31.05 15:24:19 3/17
31.05 15:24:18 3/18
31.05 15:24:17 3/18
31.05 15:24:16 3/18
31.05 15:24:16 2/18
31.05 15:24:14 2/18
31.05 15:24:13 2/18
31.05 15:24:12 3/17
31.05 15:24:11 5/18
31.05 15:24:10 5/18
31.05 15:24:09 5/19
31.05 15:24:08 5/19
31.05 15:24:07 5/19
31.05 15:24:06 5/19
31.05 15:24:05 5/19
31.05 15:24:05 5/19
31.05 15:24:03 5/19
31.05 15:24:02 5/19
31.05 15:24:01 4/19
31.05 15:24:00 4/19
31.05 15:23:59 4/19
31.05 15:23:59 4/19
31.05 15:23:57 4/19
31.05 15:23:56 4/19
31.05 15:23:55 4/19
31.05 15:23:54 4/19
31.05 15:23:53 4/19
31.05 15:23:52 4/17
31.05 15:23:51 6/18
31.05 15:23:50 7/19
31.05 15:23:49 7/19
31.05 15:23:48 7/19
31.05 15:23:47 7/18
31.05 15:23:47 7/19
31.05 15:23:45 7/18
31.05 15:23:44 7/18
31.05 15:23:43 8/18
31.05 15:23:42 9/19
31.05 15:23:41 8/18
31.05 15:23:41 9/19
31.05 15:23:39 9/19
31.05 15:23:38 9/19
31.05 15:23:37 9/19
31.05 15:23:36 9/19
31.05 15:23:35 9/19
31.05 15:23:34 9/19
31.05 15:23:33 9/19
31.05 15:23:33 9/19
31.05 15:23:32 time = 2016-05-31 15:22:07, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:23:32 9/19
31.05 15:23:32 9/19
31.05 15:23:30 9/19
31.05 15:23:30 9/19
31.05 15:23:30 9/19
31.05 15:23:30 9/19
31.05 15:23:29 time = 2016-05-31 15:22:04, Coordinates: lat = xxx, lon = xxx
31.05 15:23:29 9/19
31.05 15:23:29 9/19
31.05 15:23:28 9/19
```

Today I was moving in the car and it happened again. But this time I opened Google Maps and it was all just fine there.
So it seems like my app for whatever reason is not receiving location updates at the time when google app is receiving them

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you just have lost the signal from the satellites. Google Maps works with many sensor and radios, not just the GPS (it has algorithms to estimate your location based many sensors like the accelerometer, gyroscope, etc. and radios like cellphone, WiFi, etc.). If you want to have a continuos location retrieving then you can combine the GPS locations with other techniques and locations providers (like the network provider).

Comment: Are you talking about FusedLocationApi ? Does it call onLocationChanges() even when GPS signal is lost?

Comment: The fused location API is the custom Google's location provider. It determines the current location by multiple techniques, not only using the GPS.